# MySQL trigger not working properly

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm getting a strange error while trying to use a MySQL trigger.
I'm using XAMPP and creating the trigger using PhpMyAdmin.

The trigger's code is:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE stud INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE sw CURSOR FOR 
    (SELECT CodiceStudente FROM Listastudenticorsi WHERE CodiceCorso = NEW.CodiceCorso);

OPEN sw;

get_loop: LOOP
    FETCH sw INTO stud;     

    INSERT INTO inbox(Mittente, Destinatario, Oggetto, Contenuto, Data) VALUES (NEW.CodiceDocente, stud, "Nuova news inserita", NEW.Oggetto, NEW.Data);
END LOOP get_loop;
END
```

And is called BEFORE INSERT into the table 'News'.

What happens is that the syntax is correct, but when I try to run it triggering the event it says "#1329 - No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed".

I tried to find out what the real problem is, and it seems to be the line "FETCH sw INTO stud"; I tried many times and the SELECT statement DOES return the correct values, so 'sw' can't be empty... I'm stuck at this point.

There are 3 tables interested by this trigger. 'News' is the one that triggers the event; it has some columns that are called using the keyword "NEW". The second one is Inbox; it is the table in which I'll insert some values after the trigger has performed its actions. Finally, there's "Listastudenticorsi", which means approximately "list of students and courses".

What I do is: when a News is inserted, I get the course it refers to, its object, its date and the submitter of the news, I find (using the select statement) the students who attend the course that the News is referring to, and then send a mail to each of them using the insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no continue handler for the cursor, as I see it. It would allow that cursor to actually do something.

From the mysql `Cursor` manual page, see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html).

Here too is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32263290/1816093) to a stored proc I wrote showing a continue handler with a flag specifying done for the loop.